Converting PDF to PDF/A-2b with Itext
I have set of methods like following and I need to generate PDF/A-2b file and I need to replace the fonts in pdf if they are not embedded.
I need fix following validation errors.

The font programs for all fonts used for rendering within a
conforming file shall be embedded within that file, as defined in ISO
32000-1:2008, 9.9.

If the FontDescriptor dictionary of an embedded CID font contains a
CIDSet stream, then it shall identify all CIDs which are present in
the font program, regardless of whether a CID in the font is
referenced or used by the PDF or not.

All fonts and font programs used in a conforming file, regardless of
rendering mode usage, shall conform to the provisions in ISO
32000-1:2008, 9.6 and 9.7, as well as to the font specifications
referenced by these provisions. BaseFont - name - (Required) The
PostScript name of the font



public static byte[] convertToPDFA(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, PdfException {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
         PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream)) {

        PdfADocument pdfADoc = getPdfADocument(writer);
        try (PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(reader)) {
            srcDoc.copyPagesTo(1, srcDoc.getNumberOfPages(), pdfADoc);
        }
        pdfADoc.close();

        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
}

public static PdfADocument getPdfADocument(PdfWriter writer) throws IOException {

    String iccProfilePath = ServiceLocator.getInstance().getConfigurationService().getIccProfilePath();

    PdfOutputIntent outputIntent;
    try (InputStream iccStream = OpenHtmlToPdfUtil.class.getResourceAsStream(iccProfilePath)) {
        if (iccStream == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ICC profile not found at path: " + iccProfilePath);
        }
        outputIntent = new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "",
                "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", iccStream);
    }

    PdfADocument pdfADoc = new PdfADocument(writer, getPdfAConformanceLevel(), outputIntent);
    addPdfAMarkInfo(pdfADoc);
    return pdfADoc;
}

private static PdfAConformanceLevel getPdfAConformanceLevel() {
    switch (ServiceLocator.getInstance().getConfigurationService().getPdfAConformanceLevel()) {
        case "PDFA_2_B":
            return PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_2B;
        case "PDFA_3_A":
            return PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3A;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported pdfA conformance level is set: " +
                    ServiceLocator.getInstance().getConfigurationService().getPdfAConformanceLevel());
    }
}

private static void addPdfAMarkInfo(PdfADocument pdfDoc) {
    PdfDictionary catalog = pdfDoc.getCatalog().getPdfObject();
    PdfDictionary markInfo = catalog.getAsDictionary(PdfName.MarkInfo);
    if (markInfo == null) {
        markInfo = new PdfDictionary();
        markInfo.put(PdfName.Marked, PdfBoolean.TRUE);
        catalog.put(PdfName.MarkInfo, markInfo);
    }

    pdfDoc.setTagged();

    PdfStructTreeRoot structTreeRoot = pdfDoc.getStructTreeRoot();
    if (structTreeRoot == null) {
        structTreeRoot = new PdfStructTreeRoot(pdfDoc);
        pdfDoc.getCatalog().put(PdfName.StructTreeRoot, structTreeRoot.getPdfObject());
    }
}

